# how to stop visual studio from automatically creating an keystore file?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, keystore

i have a xamarin project, when i run it in debug mode, it automatically creating a archive (keystore file) in visual studio. how to stop it?

[image]

below is some more info
[image]

Comment: Q: Please do a "Help > About" (or equivalent) and tell us exactly what kind of "Visual Studio" you're using to develop your Xamarin app. MSVS Community 2019?  Q: Why don't you want MSVS creating the keystore?  Because you have your own?  Some other reason?

Comment: You need a keystore.  Android won't run an unsigned app.  So you generate one if one doesn't exist.

Comment: even in debug mode, it need a keystore?

Comment: Yes, even in debug mode.  The Android OS will not run an unsigned app.  If you're having problems with that because you're sharing devices around an office, I suggest one of you generate the keystore and you pass it around to all dev machines (or check it into git).

Comment: Your debug and release keystores can be (and should be) different though

Comment: Just set your default keystore from `Android Package Signing` menu for `Debug` and `Release`